# OSD set the computername based on the serialnumber for a Surface Pro 4

Tags: deployment, sccm, mdt

I'm trying to set the computername for a Surface Pro 4 based on the serialnumber.
I added the variable to my CustomSetting file as follow : ComputerName=MTLSP%SerialNumber%, but my task sequence fails when it comes to assign the name.

Am I missing something ?

PS : we use the assettag variable for desktops|laptops and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Computer names can be a maximum of 16 digits.  Surface Pro 4 serial numbers are 12 digits.  Prepending 5 characters to that exceeds the limit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable you need to use is OSDComputerName.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically set the computer name you will want to skip the deployment wizard step that asks for the computer name and then specify the computer name on the back end.

---

**Skip deployment wizard name gathering step**

Add this to your `cusotmsettings.ini` file:

`SkipComputerName=YES`

---

**Name the computer on the back end**

Next you will need to specify what the computer name will be since it will now not ask the user for the name.

You can do this by indicating what the computer name should be by using this variable in your `customsettings.ini` file.

`OSDComputerName=computer-name-here`

You can use variables in your `OSDComputerName` setting, E.G.:

`OSDComputerName=PC_%SerialNumber%` or
`OSDComputerName=MTLSP%SerialNumber%`

---

**Links**

https://scriptimus.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/mdt-2010-setting-the-default-computername/

---

**TL;DR**

Make sure that you skip the deployment wizard step and then use the correct variable to automatically name your computer. You can do that with the below `customsetting.ini` settings:

`SkipComputerName=yes
OSDComputerName=PC_%SerialNumber%`